# Weak or Unowned in this example?

Tags: swift, reference, automatic-ref-counting

I have a code like this:

```
open class WebServiceOperation: Operation {

    public init(dependencies: [Operation]? = nil, finishBlock: ((_ operation: WebServiceOperation) -> Void)? = nil) {
        super.init()

        completionBlock = { [weak self, finishBlock] in
            guard let `self` = self, self.isCancelled == false else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                finishBlock?(self)
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

I was wondering if I should use unowned instead of weak in completionBlock.
First - completionBlock is a block that is executed only by Operation object itself, so self inside it will not be nil. Thats why it could be unowned. But later self it's passed to finishBlock?() as a parameter. This will retain self for that finishBlock. Also this passing is done in DispatchQueue.main.sync block, which should also retain self.
So is it safe and correct to use unowned self in completionBlock instead of weak?